# Logging strings using nested conditionals

Tags: javascript, nested, conditional-statements

So I'm doing a tutorial that's having me practice nested conditionals. My problem is that I don't quite and understand how could use nested conditionals in this instance. Here's the instructions:
Use a "for" statement to log the number 1 - 20. If a number is divisible by 3 print "Fizz", if a number is divisible by 5 print "Buzz", if a number is divisible by 3 and 5 print "FizzBuzz", otherwise print the number.
Can someone explain to me how I can do this assignment using nested conditionals?

Comment: take your pick: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your pb, are you looking something like that

```
var i;

for(i=1;i<=20;i++){
     if ((i %3 == 0)&&(i %5 == 0))
          console.log("FizzBuzz");
     else if (i %5 == 0)
          console.log("Buzz");
     else if (i %3 == 0) 
          console.log("Fizz");
}
```

Edit, you would mean something far-fetched like that ?

```
var i;
for(i=1;i<=20;i++){
     if ((i %3 == 0)||(i %5 == 0)){
         if ((i %3 == 0)&& !(i %5 == 0))
             console.log("Buzz"); 
         else if ((i %5 == 0)&& !(i %3 == 0)) 
             console.log("Fizz");            
         else
             console.log("FizzBuzz"); 
     }        
}
```

Edit 2, Perhaps more simply, you could use that

var i;

```
for(i=1;i<=20;i++){
     if ((i %3 == 0)||(i %5 == 0)){
         if (i==15)
             console.log("FizzBuzz"); 
         else if ((i %3 == 0))
             console.log("Buzz"); 
         else 
             console.log("Fizz"); 
     }        
}
```

Comment: This is the initial exercise, but in addition to this it wants me to somehow include nested conditionals. Which, in this instance, I don't understand how I can include nested conditionals.